¿Cómo redirigir a los usuario a mi aplicación luego de que hayan reestablecido su contraseña mediante el link enviado por Firebase? Android Studio
Hola comunidad de Stackoverflow, espero puedan ayudarme a encontrar una solución para mi problema y se los agradezco de antemano. Resulta que estoy creando una aplicación nativa ANDROID y estoy trabajando en la funcionalidad de reestablecer la contraseña para el usuario. Estoy utilizando firebase authentication para manejar proveedores sociales como Google y también el nativo de correo y contraseña, pero también tengo implementada una base de datos local sqlite mediante la biblioteca ROOM donde hasta el momento tengo solo 1 tabla de usuarios (me sirve como una copia local de datos). Para mandar el link de reseteo de contraseña utilizo el método "sendPasswordResetEmail" y me funciona perfectamente, firebase manda el correo con un link predeterminado que me lleva a una página web donde se puede reestablecer la contraseña y todo bien, pero eso solo me sirve para actualizarla en firebase pero también necesito actualizarla en mi db local y eso es lo que aún no se cómo hacer. La IA me dijo que puedo hacer uso de "deep link" o "dynamic link" mediante firebase para redirigir a los usuario a mi app luego de que reestablezcan su contraseña (donde irian a una activity o fragment para que vuelvan a introducir la contraseña) y esto lo usuario a modo de "confirmacion" y aquí es donde actualizaría la contraseña en la db local. Adjunto foto del código para no morir ignorado xd.

El código siempre como texto, con formato, ya que no todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
